# Should I use Alarms or CountDownTimer, or both?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, countdowntimer

I'm a Android Studio beginner and trying to build an app. Its main function is to display count down timers to predefined (by me not the user) time points, and give user a push notification 5 minutes before the count down reaches 0.

I used `CountDownTimer` and it only display the remaining time between now and the next set time point. Right now the app does the following: checks the current day of week and displays only "today"'s schedule using a `switch` statement, counts down to the next time point, when that time point is reached, the time point text disappears; timer starts counting towards the next time point.

I'd like to improve it but have the feeling that a total revamp is needed. Here are a few things explained in text and an image:

1) The app displays remaining times for all set time points. For example, right now is 1AM, the next set time points are 2AM, 2:10AM, 5AM... Then the count down timers should be 1:00:00, 1:10:00 and 4:00:00... (Right now my app has only 1 `CountDownTimer` and only display 1 countdown, which shows the `1:00:00`. Should I use Alarms instead? And does Alarms have some sort of countdown function to display remaining time?)

2) Basically the predefined time points are same for the day of week, i.e. Mondays have the same time points 1AM, 5AM, 7AM etc..., and so do Tuesday but at 2AM, 6AM etc... I'd like to make the app to display the whole week's schedule (explained in image below), one problem I encountered is when trying to put the past time point to the end of array with extra hours added.

[image]

Also, what is a good approach when trying to create multiple time points in the same day, use Alarms? Because right now I use `long` variables (in millisecond), i.e. 1AM = 3600000 etc, which I think may not be the best practice.

Sorry for the long post, and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

u should use Handler for update UI every second when app is open and you should  use Alarm for showing notification.